# Why isn't the Intel x86 Atom available for APIs below 15?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've been using intel x86 emulator for API's above 15. I installed it from SDK tools in Android Studio. However, it doesn't seem to be available for API 14 and below. This is what I see for API 14:

[image]

However, this is what I see for API 15

[image]

I believe because of this I am having a horrible time starting an emulator with API 14. Most of the times it freezes and when it does start, I can't seem to click or do anything inside the emulator.

Comment: Why?  Probably because API 15 was current (or close to) when they developed that sort of emulator.  There are likely alternate/unofficial VM emulation solutions available corresponding to earlier APIs.  In general a device is preferable, though finding one with a specific old API can be a pain.

Comment: There is an x86 emulator image for API Level 10 in the SDK Manager. IMHO, at this point, there are no other relevant API levels -- Android 2.2 and 3.2 combine to be [1.1% of the market](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), and everything else below 15 exist only in trace amounts.